# BLE Android Studio ERROR 128 WHEN TRYING TO WRITE TO DEVICE

Tags: java, android, bluetooth-lowenergy

We can read from the device into the terminal, but we continue to receive the 128 after attempting to write to the characteristic. We are attempting write 0x00 to the characteristic which will turn off all of the LEDs on the device.

```
sendData.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       public void onClick(View v) {
           byte[] test = {00};
           mBluetoothLeService.writeCharacteristic(c,test);
           return;
       }
});

—-------------------------------------------------------------------------

public void writeCharacteristic(BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, byte[] test ) {
   if (mBluetoothAdapter == null || test == null) {
       Log.w(TAG, "BluetoothAdapter not initialized");
       return;
   }
   


characteristic.setWriteType(BluetoothGattCharacteristic.WRITE_TYPE_DEFAULT);
   characteristic.setValue(test);
   if (writeEnabled) {
       mBluetoothGatt.writeCharacteristic(characteristic);
   }
```

Comment: please post the complete stack trace of your error, that way it will be easier for other members to debug it

Comment: have you tried a generic BLE scanner like [nRF Connect](https://www.nordicsemi.com/Products/Development-tools/nrf-connect-for-mobile) to test your device?